# Do people study this generalized Brill-Noether theory for two sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, brill-noether

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$. Choose two sets of degree and rank $(d_i,r_i)$ for $i=1,2$. Let $U(d_i,r_i)$ denote the moduli space of vector bundles of degree $d_i$ and rank $r_i$ for $i=1,2$. I want to determine the dimension of vector spaces of the following form
$$\mathrm{Hom}_C(E_2,E_1),\quad [E_i]\in U(d_i,r_i).$$

When $d_1/r_1<d_2/r_2$, we have $\mathrm{Hom}(E_2,E_1)=0$. Then we only need to consider when $d_1/r_1\geq d_2/r_2$. Similar to classical Brill-Noether theory, we can define for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ a subset $B^k\subseteq U(d_1,r_1)\times U(d_2,r_2)$
$$B^k:=\{(E_1,E_2)\in U(d_1,r_1)\times U(d_2,r_2): \dim\mathrm{Hom}(E_2,E_1)\geq k\}.$$

Then we can ask similar questions:

1. For which $d_1,r_1,d_2,r_2,k$ do we have $B^k\ne\emptyset$? How about the non-emptyness of $B^k\setminus B^{k+1}$?
2. For $d_i,r_i,k$, do we have an expected dimension for $B^k$?
3. How about the smoothness/irreducibility/connectedness of $B^k$?

I come up with this question when reading the [study](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.01260.pdf) of Twisted Brill-Noether loci by Hitching, Hoff, and Newstead. Also, the non-emptyness results seem to be used in this [study](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.08986.pdf) of moduli of unstable bundles of HN length 2 by Brambila-Paz and Sierra.